# Extract numbers from ggplot created using ggQC

Tags: r

I am using ggQC to create control charts.
What I want to do is extract the UCL and LCL numbers into their own objects. The code below produces the graph:

```
Golden_Egg_df <- data.frame(month=1:12,
                            egg_diameter = rnorm(n = 12, mean = 1.5, sd = 0.2)
)

library(ggplot2)
library(ggQC)

XmR_Plot <- ggplot(Golden_Egg_df, aes(x = month, y = egg_diameter)) +
  geom_point() + geom_line() + 
  stat_QC(method = "XmR", auto.label = T)

XmR_Plot
```

[image]

The UCL is 1.9 and LCL is 1. The desired result I would be looking for would be something like the below so the numbers would be within their own objects.

```
ucl<-1.9
lcl<-1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand your question. So have assumed you want a way to create objects `UCL` and `LCL` with values taken from the graph.

With `ggplot_build()` you can inspect the data that lies under the ggplot hood and fish out what you need. In this case...

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggQC)

set.seed(123)

Golden_Egg_df <- 
  data.frame(month=1:12,
             egg_diameter = rnorm(n = 12, mean = 1.5, sd = 0.2))

XmR_Plot <- ggplot(Golden_Egg_df, aes(x = month, y = egg_diameter)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() + 
  stat_QC(method = "XmR", auto.label = TRUE)


#UCL
ggplot_build(XmR_Plot)$data[[3]][4, "label"]
#> [1] "2.1"

#LCL
ggplot_build(XmR_Plot)$data[[3]][3, "label"]
#> [1] "1"


XmR_Plot
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>